# ¿Error al comparar fechas dentro de un IF con JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando un sitio web donde al momento que sea fecha y hora especifica entonces me mande una alerta con texto, si se pasa de la fecha y hora establecida que mande otro texto.

El problema aquí es que comparando las primeras fechas con hora me funciona bien es decir con las del día 13, pero cuando pruebo con la fecha del día siguiente no funciona (día 14). En el codigo siguiente se transmite mejor lo que quiero hacer.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
          var fechas = new Date();
          var fecha = fechas.getFullYear() + '-' + ( fechas.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + fechas.getDate();
          var hora = fechas.getHours() + ':' + fechas.getMinutes() + ':' + fechas.getSeconds();
          var fechaYHora = "2021-9-14 10:16:0";
          var pan1 = "2021-9-13 10:0:0";
          var pan2 = "2021-9-13 11:0:0";
          var pan3 = "2021-9-13 12:0:0";
          var pan4 = "2021-9-13 13:0:0";
          var pan5 = "2021-9-13 14:0:0";
          var pan6 = "2021-9-13 15:0:0";
          var tiempo1 = "2021-9-13 16:0:0";
          var pan7 = "2021-9-14 9:0:0";
          var pan8 = "2021-9-14 13:0:0";

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Son las " + fechaYHora + " horas";

       
       if (fechaYHora >= pan7 && fechaYHora < pan8) {
                    alert("panel7");

         $("#agrandaralerta").click(function(){
            alert("alertapan7");
            $('#sintransmisionid').empty();
            $("#mensaje_alertaid").addClass("mensaje_alerta");  
            $("#mensaje_alertaid").addClass("mensaje_cambio");
            $("#mensjaetextid7").removeClass("mensajetext");
          });
         $("#minimizaralerta").click(function(){
            $("#mensaje_alertaid").addClass("mensaje_alerta");  
            $("#mensaje_alertaid").addClass("mensaje_alerta");
            $("#mensjaetextid7").addClass("mensajetext"); 
          });
     }
}
```

En este ejemplo se enfoca en la variable `pan7` y `pan8`. Por ejemplo:
Si la variable `fechaYHora` es mayo o igual a `pan7` y `fechaYHora` es menor a `pan8`, entonces muestra una alerta con un texto. Si `pan8` es mayor entonces la alerta ya no funcionaria.

Entonces en mi código JS si dejo como `fechaYHora >= pan7` aqué si me funciona pero agrego la otra condición que es `&& fechaYHora < pan8`, entonces ya no entra en el IF, no se a que se deba, si la variable `pan8` es igual a una fecha mas elevada que la variable FechaYHora. Cabe aclarar que la variable `FechaYHora` es menor a  `"2021-9-14 13:0:0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás comparando strings sin un estándar de formato definido.

Te sugiero que utilices el objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) directamente para comparar las fechas. Tu código debería ser así:

```js
var fechaYHora = new Date("2021-9-14 10:16:0");
var pan7 = new Date("2021-9-14 9:0:0");
var pan8 = new Date("2021-9-14 13:0:0");
   
if (fechaYHora >= pan7 && fechaYHora < pan8) {
  console.log("fechaYHora es >= que pan7 y < que pan8");
  alert("panel7");
}
```

---

EDIT:

La otra opción es respetar un formato en tus strings:

```js
let fechaYHora = "2021-9-14 10:16:0";
let pan7 = "2021-9-14 9:0:0";
let pan8 = "2021-9-14 13:0:0";

// fechaYHora es menor al string pan7. Ya que javascript está comparando cadenas de texto y no sabe que son fechas
console.log("fechaYHora >= pan7 -> ",fechaYHora >= pan7); 


// Si quieres comparar las cadenas debes seguir un formato que permita que la comparación de las cadenas también sirva para comparar las fechas.
pan7 = "2021-9-14 09:00:00"; // Le agregamos el cero a la hora para que la cadena tenga el mismo largo
console.log("fechaYHora >= pan7 -> ",fechaYHora >= pan7);
```

---

Por lo tanto deberías usar el mismo formato para representar fechas con tus strings:

```js
var fechaYHora = "2021-9-14 10:16:00";
var pan7 = "2021-9-14 09:00:00"; // <- Antes este string era menor (en caracteres) que los demás, por eso "fechaYHora >= pan7" era falso
var pan8 = "2021-9-14 13:00:00";

if (fechaYHora >= pan7 && fechaYHora < pan8) {
  console.log("fechaYHora es >= que pan7 y < que pan8");
  alert("panel7");
}
```

Para comparar con `==` debes pasar a string la fecha, ya que si no, se compara el objeto en si y no el valor:

```js
let fecha1 = new Date("2021-10-10 10:00:00");
let fecha2 = new Date("2021-10-10 10:00:00");

console.log("fecha1 == fecha2 ->", fecha1 == fecha2);

console.log("fecha1.toString() == fecha2.toString() ->", fecha1.toString() == fecha2.toString());
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ahora entiendo, si ahora si entra a la condición, pero no entiendo por que cuando estaba en el día 13 y comparaba pan1, pan2, pan3,pan4 entre otros, si funcionaba.

Comment: Si quieres comparar strings entonces ten en cuenta el formato de la fecha en los strings. La hora en `pan7`  debería ser "09:00:00" y no "9:0:0".

Comment: Edité la pregunta para ejemplificar lo que comentas

Comment: Gracias, sobre la primer respuesta probé de esa manera y si funciona, pero no al momento que una condición es == , por ejemplo: pan1 == fechaYHora sin en cambio si establezco pan1 <= fechaYHora si funciona pero al momento que la hora y fecha sea la misma que la variable pan1, no funciona, tengo una alerta para ser detectado cuando sea igual.

Comment: Claro, el problema con javascript es que el en el `==` compara instancias de objetos y no los valores de fecha como en el `>=` o los otros. Si necesitas usar `==` puedes usar `fecha.toString() == pan1.toString()` Ya edité la pregunta con ese caso

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, utilice lo que comentaste, el objeto Date y como no comparaba con == entonces use lo también dicho y el resultado seria así  pan1.toString() == fechaYHora . Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y ayuda.